# Showing list in panel in sencha touch

Tags: list, sencha-touch-2.1

I am basically making 2 horixzontal panel to split the screen for ipad.

I am trying to show list in left panel and a detail view in right panel but any how I am not getting the list.

below is the view which I am using:

```
Ext.define("Sencha.view.Main", {
extend: 'Ext.Container',    
config: {

layout: 'hbox',

    items: [
    {
        xtype: 'panel',
        width: 300,
        items: [

                {
                    xtype: "list",
                    id:'contactlist',
                    store:'Items',
                }
                 ],
    },
    {
        xtype: 'panel',
        html: 'Message Detail view goes here ....'

    }
]
}
```

});

Below is the store which I am using:

```
Ext.define('Sencha.store.Items', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

config: {
    model: 'Sencha.model.Item',
    defaultRootProperty: 'items',
    root: {
        items: [
            {
                text: 'Drinks',

            },
            {
                text: 'Snacks',

            }
        ]
    }
}
```

});

Comment: you might need to specify `height` because this is not a `fit` layout and container also doesn't have any height specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you might be missing the flex config option in the list as stated in the sencha docs and the itemTpl

```
{
      xtype: "list",
      id:'contactlist',
      flex: 1,
      itemTpl: {text},
      store:'Items',
}
```

docs:
"The flex of this item if this item item is inside a Ext.layout.HBox or Ext.layout.VBox layout."

also there is no storeId set for the store. storeId: 'Items',